# How can I understand/visualise this (finite) set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

$$B_{\epsilon}=\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Bbb Z\right)\cap [-1,1]$$

This is given as a hint for a question but its not of much help since I am not quite sure what this even is.

The question is asking that I use this set to prove that

$S_{\epsilon}=\{(y_n): y_n\in B_{\epsilon} \text{ and } y_n=0 \text{ }  \forall n>N_\epsilon\}\cap  S$  is a net for $S$ if $N_\epsilon$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: It's the set of roots between $[-1, 1]$ of a sine function $x \mapsto \sin(\alpha x)$, for some $\alpha$ related to $\epsilon$ which I can't be bothered to work out exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set contains all the numbers
$$
0, \pm\epsilon/2, \pm\epsilon, \pm 3\epsilon/2, \ldots
$$
that happen to like in the interval $[-1,1]$. It's a bunch of points spaced $\epsilon/2$ apart on the number line.

I havent't thought about the question it's a hint for the solution of.